# Perl replace not working as expected

Tags: regex, perl

I want to replace the multiple js file block to a minified version using perl command.

When I tested it on online website, it works
but when I run in command line, it does not.

```
echo '<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
      <!-- build:js ../ute.min.js -->
      <script src="app/app.js"></script>
      <script src="app/services/uteEndpoint.js"></script>
      <!-- endbuild:js -->' |  perl -pe 's/<!-- build:js ([^ ]+) -->[^\!]+<!-- endbuild:js -->/<script src="$1"><\/script>/gm'
```

What am I doing wrong in command line?

I have tested here, http://www.regexe.com/, and my expected output is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="../ute.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Perl processes the input line by line. Since you're working with multiple lines, you need to enable paragraph  mode.

```
perl -00pe 's~<!-- build:js ([^ ]+) -->[^\!]+<!-- endbuild:js -->~<script src="$1"></script>~gm'
```

OR

```
perl -0777pe 's~<!-- build:js ([^ ]+) -->[^\!]+<!-- endbuild:js -->~<script src="$1"></script>~gm'
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo '<!doctype html>
>     <html>
>     <head>
>       <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
>       <!-- build:js ../ute.min.js -->
>       <script src="app/app.js"></script>
>       <script src="app/services/uteEndpoint.js"></script>
>       <!-- endbuild:js -->' |  perl -0777pe 's/<!-- build:js ([^ ]+) -->[^\!]+<!-- endbuild:js -->/<script src="$1"><\/script>/gm'
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="../ute.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to learn what slurp mode is. learning never ends :)

Comment: `-00` is paragraph mode, it just works by coincidence because the input does not have two consecutive newlines. See `perldoc -v "$/"` for more info.

Comment: yep, that's what i said. Perl splits the input according to two newline characters. I think the term slurp is wrong here. So that i added `-0777pe`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Well, using `-00` is wrong, no matter what you call it. Using `-0777` is correct.